# Загрузка изображений с okhttp

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте. Необходимо реализовать загрузку изображений в okhttp3, сколько гуглил - нормального ответа не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: вы имеете ввиду загрузку файлов изображений?

Comment: да, загрузку файлов изображений

Answer (score 0):

Okhttp - это HTTP клиент, исходя из чего можно сделать вывод, что ему абсолютно без разницы - изображение это или какой- то другой тип файла. Загрузка происходит одинаково.

Готовый пример доступен здесь:
https://github.com/dazza5000/OkHttpDownloadImage/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/tipit/okhttpspike/MainActivity.java